# Where am i wrong?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Where does my logic for the answer of the 2nd part of the question goes wrong?

[Probability of sampling with and without replacement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489772/probability-of-sampling-with-and-without-replacement/489783#489783)

Comment: Right at the beginning: it simply isn’t a stars-and-bars problem.

Comment: exactly! why can't it be seen as choosing r elements from n distinct elements when repetition of elements is allowed? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Because the order of the choices makes a difference. You’re not just choosing a multiset of $r$ elements: you’re choosing an ordered $r$-tuple of elements. Moreover, there is constant sum involved.

Comment: It's sampling(selection), order should not matter!

Comment: When you sample **with replacement**, you pick your sample in some particular order, so you can end up with the same multiset in more than one way.

Comment: Anyway, could you list all the possible sampling cases for elements(1,2,3,4) and all desirable sampling cases satisfying the condition that element '1' is not selected.[Just to verify please :)] with replacement allowed

Comment: $222,333,444,223,232,322,224,242,422,233,323,332,334,343,433,442,424,244,443,434,344,234,243,324,342,423,432$

Comment: okay then! I suppose for the 1st question we got lucky .We considered combination instead of permutation but
 since [r*P(n-1,r-1)]/[P(n,r)] would also give (r/n) we got spared @BrianM.Scott

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to use combinations for the first problem, provided that you use them both in counting the acceptable sets and in counting the total possible number of sets. It's also perfectly acceptable to use permutations for both. You should try it: if you do it right, you'll get the same result both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for without replacement :- total no. of possible ways of selecting $r$ elements from $n$ elements = $nCr$
total no. of ways where element x is always selected would be equal to selecting $(r−1)$ element from $(n−1)$ elements [as we would consider $x$ to be already selected] ,

which would be = $(n−1)C(r−1)$
probability =
$(n−1)C(r−1)nCr=rn$
:-> C is the combination

for with replacement :-

total possible no. of selections would be $= C(n+r-1,r)$ [bars and star logic]

total cases where element $x$ is never selected are $= C(n+r-2,r)$ [$n$ reduces to $n-1$]

probability of at least one selection of element $x = [1 - {C(n+r-2,r)}/{C(n+r-1,r)}]$

which comes out to be $= (n-1)/(n+r-1)$

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of what is called [Theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_two) of the [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) which relates to " the number of distinct n-tuples of non-negative integers whose sum is k". Here we are not concerned with any sum - the sum does not matter, just the presence or absence of the fixed element.

### Edit for request in comments:

There are 256 possibilities with four elements. According to the other question, the answer should be $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^r = 1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4 = 1-\frac{81}{256} = \frac{175}{256}$ So, assuming our fixed element is $2$ we should expect $175$ instances of the strings to **not** have a $2$. The list is enumerated below with a column which has a $1$ if the row contains a $2$ and 0 otherwise. I leave it up to you to copy this into a spreadsheet and see for yourself that the sum of the indicator is $175$.

```
Tuple   No "2" Indicator
{1,1,1,1}   0
{1,1,1,2}   1
{1,1,1,3}   0
{1,1,1,4}   0
{1,1,2,1}   1
{1,1,2,2}   1
{1,1,2,3}   1
{1,1,2,4}   1
{1,1,3,1}   0
{1,1,3,2}   1
{1,1,3,3}   0
{1,1,3,4}   0
{1,1,4,1}   0
{1,1,4,2}   1
{1,1,4,3}   0
{1,1,4,4}   0
{1,2,1,1}   1
{1,2,1,2}   1
{1,2,1,3}   1
{1,2,1,4}   1
{1,2,2,1}   1
{1,2,2,2}   1
{1,2,2,3}   1
{1,2,2,4}   1
{1,2,3,1}   1
{1,2,3,2}   1
{1,2,3,3}   1
{1,2,3,4}   1
{1,2,4,1}   1
{1,2,4,2}   1
{1,2,4,3}   1
{1,2,4,4}   1
{1,3,1,1}   0
{1,3,1,2}   1
{1,3,1,3}   0
{1,3,1,4}   0
{1,3,2,1}   1
{1,3,2,2}   1
{1,3,2,3}   1
{1,3,2,4}   1
{1,3,3,1}   0
{1,3,3,2}   1
{1,3,3,3}   0
{1,3,3,4}   0
{1,3,4,1}   0
{1,3,4,2}   1
{1,3,4,3}   0
{1,3,4,4}   0
{1,4,1,1}   0
{1,4,1,2}   1
{1,4,1,3}   0
{1,4,1,4}   0
{1,4,2,1}   1
{1,4,2,2}   1
{1,4,2,3}   1
{1,4,2,4}   1
{1,4,3,1}   0
{1,4,3,2}   1
{1,4,3,3}   0
{1,4,3,4}   0
{1,4,4,1}   0
{1,4,4,2}   1
{1,4,4,3}   0
{1,4,4,4}   0
{2,1,1,1}   1
{2,1,1,2}   1
{2,1,1,3}   1
{2,1,1,4}   1
{2,1,2,1}   1
{2,1,2,2}   1
{2,1,2,3}   1
{2,1,2,4}   1
{2,1,3,1}   1
{2,1,3,2}   1
{2,1,3,3}   1
{2,1,3,4}   1
{2,1,4,1}   1
{2,1,4,2}   1
{2,1,4,3}   1
{2,1,4,4}   1
{2,2,1,1}   1
{2,2,1,2}   1
{2,2,1,3}   1
{2,2,1,4}   1
{2,2,2,1}   1
{2,2,2,2}   1
{2,2,2,3}   1
{2,2,2,4}   1
{2,2,3,1}   1
{2,2,3,2}   1
{2,2,3,3}   1
{2,2,3,4}   1
{2,2,4,1}   1
{2,2,4,2}   1
{2,2,4,3}   1
{2,2,4,4}   1
{2,3,1,1}   1
{2,3,1,2}   1
{2,3,1,3}   1
{2,3,1,4}   1
{2,3,2,1}   1
{2,3,2,2}   1
{2,3,2,3}   1
{2,3,2,4}   1
{2,3,3,1}   1
{2,3,3,2}   1
{2,3,3,3}   1
{2,3,3,4}   1
{2,3,4,1}   1
{2,3,4,2}   1
{2,3,4,3}   1
{2,3,4,4}   1
{2,4,1,1}   1
{2,4,1,2}   1
{2,4,1,3}   1
{2,4,1,4}   1
{2,4,2,1}   1
{2,4,2,2}   1
{2,4,2,3}   1
{2,4,2,4}   1
{2,4,3,1}   1
{2,4,3,2}   1
{2,4,3,3}   1
{2,4,3,4}   1
{2,4,4,1}   1
{2,4,4,2}   1
{2,4,4,3}   1
{2,4,4,4}   1
{3,1,1,1}   0
{3,1,1,2}   1
{3,1,1,3}   0
{3,1,1,4}   0
{3,1,2,1}   1
{3,1,2,2}   1
{3,1,2,3}   1
{3,1,2,4}   1
{3,1,3,1}   0
{3,1,3,2}   1
{3,1,3,3}   0
{3,1,3,4}   0
{3,1,4,1}   0
{3,1,4,2}   1
{3,1,4,3}   0
{3,1,4,4}   0
{3,2,1,1}   1
{3,2,1,2}   1
{3,2,1,3}   1
{3,2,1,4}   1
{3,2,2,1}   1
{3,2,2,2}   1
{3,2,2,3}   1
{3,2,2,4}   1
{3,2,3,1}   1
{3,2,3,2}   1
{3,2,3,3}   1
{3,2,3,4}   1
{3,2,4,1}   1
{3,2,4,2}   1
{3,2,4,3}   1
{3,2,4,4}   1
{3,3,1,1}   0
{3,3,1,2}   1
{3,3,1,3}   0
{3,3,1,4}   0
{3,3,2,1}   1
{3,3,2,2}   1
{3,3,2,3}   1
{3,3,2,4}   1
{3,3,3,1}   0
{3,3,3,2}   1
{3,3,3,3}   0
{3,3,3,4}   0
{3,3,4,1}   0
{3,3,4,2}   1
{3,3,4,3}   0
{3,3,4,4}   0
{3,4,1,1}   0
{3,4,1,2}   1
{3,4,1,3}   0
{3,4,1,4}   0
{3,4,2,1}   1
{3,4,2,2}   1
{3,4,2,3}   1
{3,4,2,4}   1
{3,4,3,1}   0
{3,4,3,2}   1
{3,4,3,3}   0
{3,4,3,4}   0
{3,4,4,1}   0
{3,4,4,2}   1
{3,4,4,3}   0
{3,4,4,4}   0
{4,1,1,1}   0
{4,1,1,2}   1
{4,1,1,3}   0
{4,1,1,4}   0
{4,1,2,1}   1
{4,1,2,2}   1
{4,1,2,3}   1
{4,1,2,4}   1
{4,1,3,1}   0
{4,1,3,2}   1
{4,1,3,3}   0
{4,1,3,4}   0
{4,1,4,1}   0
{4,1,4,2}   1
{4,1,4,3}   0
{4,1,4,4}   0
{4,2,1,1}   1
{4,2,1,2}   1
{4,2,1,3}   1
{4,2,1,4}   1
{4,2,2,1}   1
{4,2,2,2}   1
{4,2,2,3}   1
{4,2,2,4}   1
{4,2,3,1}   1
{4,2,3,2}   1
{4,2,3,3}   1
{4,2,3,4}   1
{4,2,4,1}   1
{4,2,4,2}   1
{4,2,4,3}   1
{4,2,4,4}   1
{4,3,1,1}   0
{4,3,1,2}   1
{4,3,1,3}   0
{4,3,1,4}   0
{4,3,2,1}   1
{4,3,2,2}   1
{4,3,2,3}   1
{4,3,2,4}   1
{4,3,3,1}   0
{4,3,3,2}   1
{4,3,3,3}   0
{4,3,3,4}   0
{4,3,4,1}   0
{4,3,4,2}   1
{4,3,4,3}   0
{4,3,4,4}   0
{4,4,1,1}   0
{4,4,1,2}   1
{4,4,1,3}   0
{4,4,1,4}   0
{4,4,2,1}   1
{4,4,2,2}   1
{4,4,2,3}   1
{4,4,2,4}   1
{4,4,3,1}   0
{4,4,3,2}   1
{4,4,3,3}   0
{4,4,3,4}   0
{4,4,4,1}   0
{4,4,4,2}   1
{4,4,4,3}   0
{4,4,4,4}   0
```

Comment: could you list all the possible sampling cases for elements(1,2,3,4) and all desirable sampling cases satisfying the condition that element '1' is not selected.[Just to verify please :)] with replacement allowed  @Avraham

Comment: @AtulGangwar The answer has been edited to show your request (although I used "2" instead of "1" 8-) ).

Comment: what about this comment of mine "okay then! I suppose for the 1st question we got lucky .We considered combination instead of permutation but since [r*P(n-1,r-1)]/[P(n,r)] would also give (r/n) we got spared"

Comment: When sampling **without** replacement, combinations *are* what we want since order doesn't matter, so you were correct. It doesn't matter in either case. I don't think I used order in the derivation of with or without.