# 2 balls out of 3 draw balls

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn contains 2 red balls, 2 blue balls and 2 green balls.

3 balls are drawn.

a) What is the probability of getting 2 blue balls *with* replacement
a) What is the probability of getting 2 blue balls *without* replacement

Comment: Hello, @n3xus, welcome to MSE. Can you please add in the question what you have tried yourself? Questions that do no shown any efforts are usually poorly received.

Comment: Answers to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489772/probability-of-sampling-with-and-without-replacement) may help with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have **2R,2B and 2G** balls.

For **a**:
draw first ball, replace it, draw second, replace, draw third.
(total balls are always 6)
Possible outcomes: **BBR** and **BBG**    with re-arranged order.
Re-arrangement will occur in $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways  because B is repeated twice.

For **BBR** like outcomes:(BBR,BRB,RBB)
probability is $$\frac26 \frac 26  \frac26 \frac{3!}{2!}$$
For **BBG** like outcomes:(BBG,BGB,GBB)
 probability is $$\frac26 \frac 26  \frac26 \frac{3!}{2!}$$
Total is: $$2( \frac26 \frac 26  \frac26 \frac{3!}{2!})$$

---

For **b**:draw 3 balls simultaneously without replacement.
(A ball decreases with each draw)
Required outcomes: BBR and GBB, with re-arranged order.
For **BBR**: probability is $$\frac26 \frac 15  \frac24 $$
For **BRB**: probability is $$\frac26 \frac 25  \frac14 $$
For **RBB**: probability is $$\frac26 \frac 25  \frac14 $$
Proceed similarly for **BBG**.

Total is: $$6( \frac{2\cdot2\cdot1}{6\cdot5\cdot4})$$